# Does using saved Google Text-to-Speech audio files violate Google Cloud Usage Terms?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

My app has a list of **fixed paragraphs** that needs to be translated into speech. I plan to use [Google's Text-to-Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech) to convert them into speech then download their audio files so that I don't need to constantly communicate with the API to translate them, considering that the paragraphs, once again, do not change.

Does this violate the [Google Cloud Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/terms) restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news. It seems that caching synthesized audio files to avoid re-synthesization and promote cost saving is allowed with Google Text-to-Speech, as promoted by one of their [use cases](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/text-to-speech-epg-demo).